# Creating a a multiple-polygon shapefile from CSV

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap

```
   ID,X,Y
1,-79.378,42.2
1,-79.34,42.252
1,-79.338,42.206
1,-79.413,42.18
2,-79.637,42.26
2,-79.735,42.262
2,-79.731,42.163
2,-79.619,42.124
```

This is my CSV File. I need to convert this to a feature class that contains 2 polygons. I have access to ArcPy and ArcMap. I will include the code that I have been trying to use, but haven't had much luck yet. Any Ideas?

```
import csv
import arcpy

csvfile='C:\\Users\\Tables\\Table.csv'
outpath= 'C:\\Users\\Folder
outshp='test52.shp'

outshp = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (
    outpath, outshp, geometry_type='POLYGON',
    spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))

arcpy.AddField_management(outshp, "ID", "LONG")

with open(csvfile) as csvfile, arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outshp, ['X, Y']) as cursor:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    #Skip header row
    next(csvreader, None)

    for id, coords in csvreader:
        coords = [('X', 'Y')]
        print "Polygon creation successful!"
        cursor.insertRow([id, coords])
```

Comment: This isn't a multpolygon, it's two single-part polygons. your loop logic would nearly be okay if you were populating points, but you don't capture the ID column, which is critical to solving polygon construction. You need to add an `activeID` flag (initialized to something which won't occur) and an empty array outside the loop, and then change the loop to look for ID change (in which case a row is written if the array is not empty, and then the array is cleared), otherwise you need to append a `Point` to the `Array`. Make the insert code a function, since you need to call it after loop end.

Comment: Could you show what you mean in code format by chance? I am very new to python and have spent forever on this.

Comment: You also need to capture the as-is SpatialReference above the loop and apply that in the `arcpy.Polygon` constructor. You may need to append the zeroth point at write, to close the polygon.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure what most of what you just said means haha.

Comment: There are tons of code examples in the ArcPy documentation for `Polygon` and `da.InsertCursor`. There's even several "Working with coordinates" topics. At a minimum, you can get your code working to the point that IDs are captured and polygon change is detected.

Comment: I would dispense with the `csv` module and just use Excel To Table and a 1arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` to read the table rows.

Comment: You should definitely have a look here https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/writing-geometries.htm

Answer (score 1):

Adapting your code to the one in [this official esri documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/writing-geometries.htm) page, you could do something like this:

```
import csv
import arcpy

csvfile='C:\\Users\\Tables\\Table.csv'
outpath= 'C:\\Users\\Folder'
outshp='test52.shp'
spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

outshp = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (
    outpath, outshp, geometry_type='POLYGON',
    spatial_reference=spatial_reference)

arcpy.AddField_management(outshp, "ID", "LONG")

feature_class = outshp[0]

with open(csvfile) as csv_file, arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@', 'ID']) as cursor:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    #Skip header row
    next(csvreader, None)

    # count number of rows in CSV (skipping header)
    row_count = sum(1 for row in csvreader)

    # reset iterator and recreate the reader
    csv_file.seek(0)
    csvreader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    #Skip header row
    next(csvreader, None)

    # Create an array object needed to create features
    array = arcpy.Array()

    for i, row in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
        # if this nis the first row
        if i == 1:
            id = row[0]
        # if this is another ID
        if id != row[0]:
            polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array, spatial_reference)
            cursor.insertRow([polygon, id])
            # set new ID and reset features for new polygon
            array.removeAll() # If the ID has changed, create a new feature
            id = row[0] # update UD
        array.add(arcpy.Point(float(row[1]), float(row[2])))
        # if this is th last iteration
        if i == row_count:
            polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array, spatial_reference)
            cursor.insertRow([polygon, id])
```